After update angular 16 - property '_isScalar' does not exist on type 'Observable<any[]>'
I recently updated to angular 16 from V15, After change the observable which we declared doesn't contain/returning the propertly '_isScalar' which is worked before
"rxjs": "~7.5.5",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"@angular/core": "^16.2.12",

this is the observable
rowData = new Observable<any[]>();
we are checking this _isScalar like below
setting rowData values
this.httpSvc.getDeletedInfo(this.searchCondition.year, simpleMonth, this.searchCondition.gaId).subscribe(data => {
      this.rowData = data.DeleteInfoList;
      this.gaSvc.InitMessage();
    }, (err) => {
      this.gaSvc.isLoading = false;
    });

We are checkin internal property isscalar here
 if (this.rowData._isScalar !== false) {
   this.httpSvc.getDeletedInfo(this.searchCondition.year, this.searchCondition.month, this.searchCondition.gaId).subscribe(data => {
            this.rowData = data.DeleteInfoList;
            this.gaSvc.isLoading = false;
            params.api.paginationGoToPage(0);
          }, (error) => {
            this.gaSvc.isLoading = false;
          });
    }

 

This was perfectly working fine in angular 15 after updated to 16 application showing compilation error like below
 error TS2339: Property '_isScalar' does not exist on type 'Observable<any[]>'

259     if (this.rowData._isScalar !== false) {
~~~~~~~
I need a help here why the observable not returning _isScalar propertly or do i need to change the declaration part

See: https://rxjs.dev/6-to-7-change-summary. _isScalar property removed.

@Karthiga please share the code that uses this.rowData to suggest an alternative approach

@NarenMurali i have updated the code that uses rowData. we are using _isScalar property to check the condition . I am not very if we can remove that, i am thinking the purpose of _isScalar is to be missed

@derstauner Thank you.. Since its removed please suggest me an alternate approach or directly we can remove that from code
